# Mongodb/Redis setup

Tags: virtualization, mongodb, redis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I am contemplating purchasing/setting up a 16gb server which will contain 2 5gb instances of mongodb (multi drive replica/shard sets with remote backup with slave reads ok), a 4gb redis instance and a 2 gb postgres instance.

Couple question on this matter:

1) What kinda cpu would be idea for virtualizing and making 4 centos 6 implementations on one computer with 2 mognodb, 1 redis and a postgres instance?

2) Would a 25mb/s connection be fast enough for connecting my webservers to the databases? I.e how often is internet speed the hiderence with a database setup, is 25 goning to make a big difference from 100?

I would rather host this setup in the cloud but that costs way to much monthly especially since the app I am working on has a bit to go before it starts making revenue that I can use to pay for such a thing. Getting a $500 server that will last a long time, makes more sense to me...

Comment: $500 server?!? That's pretty funny. At that price point, all you're buying is a crappy workstation motherboard with cheap components. Hardly a "server" by any stretch. Add a zero and you'll see hardware that performs well and is resilient like a server should be.

Comment: I guess this site isnt for my kinda needs, it seems you guys do expensive/blade builds. $500 'desktop server' is likely plenty suitable for my needs, A solid cpu + 16gb + a ssd shouldnt come out to way more than that especially considering all are non cpu intensive databases. People pay $5000 for 16gb setup?!?

Comment: @NoviceCoding, server-quality motherboards with server-quality ECC memory and a server-quality processor are going to run you more than $500.   You **do not** want to have that much memory without ECC. Even the cheapest whitebox hardware you could get is going to be in the $1000-1500 range.

Comment: Commented on the answer below that relates to this, if you dont mind looking. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not to be harsh, but (even ignoring the capacity planning aspect) your entire scheme is optimistic (at best), and misguided.  Fortunately it's probably just ignorance, which can be cured.

Add a zero to your budget to start.  That will get you one beginning midrange server.  Double or Triple your existing to get a low-end server.

The processor doesn't matter all that much; just about everything is 64-bit with virtualization extensions these days.

Choose a database and learn it well.

Unless this is just for testing slaving/failover, don't put similar VMs on the same host; that's putting your eggs in the same basket, and increasing overhead with each VM.

Welcome to the community (and apparently the SysAd role).  Please take the time to read our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq), and peruse our already-answered questions.  ([A list of canonical ones are here](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/50875).)

Comment: Thanks! I have already set up mongodb (with replica sets) and redis on 3 cheap vpses with backups to s3 and what not. Thing is with openvz I have the issue of limited ram/bad virtualization etc. I figured I can setup a 'desktop server', but I get the feeling from the comments made that this website is designed more for the professional blade server kinda thing. I figured I'd get a 16gb i7 desktop and vm it up to run 4 instances of mogodb/redis since they arent that cpu intensive (more ram intensive).

Comment: Personally, I would use Redis or MongoDB, not both.  Putting multiple VMs that compete for the same resources is folly. You would be better off running separate MongoDB or Redis instances on the base OS with different files and listening on different ports that hosting discrete VMs. You don't need Blades; Standard rack or tower server hardware are adequate. You can run this on consumer hardware, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: With that amount of ram I think I'd have plenty of headroom to do what you're suggesting (instead of virtualizing just run as seperate processes). Is consumer hardware not robust enough for this kinda thing? I've tracked mongodb's cpu usage and its rarely above the single digits on my core2duo macbook, so I figured I could easily run 2 instances with a redis on something like this http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117185. Although, its probably not close to on par with what you guys deal with, its still better then those virtualized vpses they sell online, right?